# How do I manage resolv.conf with Puppet

Tags: dns, puppet

I have some hosts that have explicitly managed resolv.conf files. I have others that rely on NetworkManager, which does many things including writing the resolv.conf file. Is there a consistent way to manage this information with Pupppet, such as some module where I can describe the DNS servers and search orders semantically, then expect the right thing to happen depending on how the host is configured? Failing that, is there a module that will interface to NetworkManager to do what I want? Writing out an explicit resolv.conf file is fairly trivial, so I need no help with that if I go that route.

Answer (score 1):

You can create if statements before your manifests:
* if NetworkManager is not installed, use **file_line** (one of the best puppet modules I know http://puppetlabs.com/blog/module-of-the-week-puppetlabsstdlib-puppet-labs-standard-library) to edit resolv.conf.
* else ensure NetworkManager is running.

If you want some to have the customer resolv.conf on servers that have NetowrkManager too, maybe create a custom facter? Something like default_resolv_conf and then you manifest:
if $custom_resolv_conf {
    file_line { '..':
    .....
    }

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates. Here is an example of a template:

```
domain <%= @param1 %>
search <%= @param1 %> <%= @param2 %>
nameserver <%= @dns1 %>
nameserver <%= @dns2 %>
<%= @dns1_ip6 %>
<%= @dns2_ip6 %>
```

You can add different values for these parameters in conditional statements depending on the group of nodes... e.g.:

```
 if ( $domain ){
    $param1 = $domain
    $param2 = $someOtherDomain
    $dns1 = 1.1.1.1
    $dns2 = 1.1.1.2
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have something like this for explicitly managing resolv.conf, but it doesn't really address what to do on hosts where NetworkManager generates the resolv.conf.

Answer (score 0):

This looks open for a while, but just had to deal with this myself.  The best way I found was to have puppet manage the files /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head and /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail depending on what resolv.conf options you need to add.  You can then have Puppet exec to have the updates pushed to /etc/resolv.conf:

```
    # Create a custom file to append to resolv.conf
file {'/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail':
  ensure    => present,
  mode      => '0644',
  content   => '# Custom resolv.conf options added by Puppet profiles::resolv',
} ->
# Override the default for retry attempts
file_line {"options attempts:${$attempts}":
  ensure  => present,
  path    => '/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail',
  line    => "options attempts:${$attempts}",
  match   => '^options attempts:.*',
} ->
# Force an update to resolv.conf
exec {'update-resolvconf':
  command => 'resolvconf -u',
  user    => 'root',
  path    => ['/sbin/'],
}
```